# Basis of Field F over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am self studying Field theory and got struck on this problem.

> If $\;F=\mathbb{Q} \left(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}\right),\;$ find
> $\;\left[F:\mathbb{Q}\right]\;$ and a basis of $F$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I have proved that $\left[F:\mathbb{Q}\right] =4$, but there is a problem in basis elements.

My basis set is $\left\{a, b\sqrt{2}, c\sqrt{3}\right\}$ such that $a, b, c$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}$. But what should be fourth element and why ?

I am not able to see .

Kindly help.

Comment: what about $\sqrt 6$

Comment: @Thomas Can you please explain why should I consider square  root of 6?

Comment: Because if a field contains  $\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3$ it contains the product.

Comment: @Thomas I have proved the question but then why not square root (18) , square root (12) and so on?

Comment: Because $\sqrt{18} = 3\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt{12} = 2\sqrt3$, i.e., they're scalar multiples of the basis elements $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$, respectively. On the other hand, $\sqrt6$ cannot be expressed as $q_1 \sqrt2$ or $q_2 \sqrt3$ where $q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis of $F$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\;\left\{1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6}\right\},$ indeed for any element $\;x\in F\;$ there exist $\;r_1,\;r_2,\;r_3,\;r_4,\;r_5,\;r_6,\;r_7,\;r_8\in\mathbb{Q}\;$ such that

\begin{align}
x&=\dfrac{r_1+r_2\sqrt{2}+r_3\sqrt{3}+r_4\sqrt{6}}{r_5+r_6\sqrt{2}+r_7\sqrt{3}+r_8\sqrt{6}}\\
&=\dfrac{r_1+r_2\sqrt{2}+r_3\sqrt{3}+r_4\sqrt{6}}{r_5+r_6\sqrt{2}+r_7\sqrt{3}+r_8\sqrt{6}}\cdot\dfrac{r_5+r_6\sqrt{2}-r_7\sqrt{3}-r_8\sqrt{6}}{r_5+r_6\sqrt{2}-r_7\sqrt{3}-r_8\sqrt{6}}\\
&=\dfrac{\left(r_1+r_2\sqrt{2}+r_3\sqrt{3}+r_4\sqrt{6}\right)\left(r_5+r_6\sqrt{2}-r_7\sqrt{3}-r_8\sqrt{6}\right)}{\left(r_5+r_6\sqrt{2}\right)^2-\left(r_7\sqrt{3}+r_8\sqrt{6}\right)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{s_1+s_2\sqrt{2}+s_3\sqrt{3}+s_4\sqrt{6}}{s_5+s_6\sqrt{2}}\\
&=\dfrac{s_1+s_2\sqrt{2}+s_3\sqrt{3}+s_4\sqrt{6}}{s_5+s_6\sqrt{2}}\cdot\dfrac{s_5-s_6\sqrt{2}}{s_5-s_6\sqrt{2}}\\
&=\dfrac{\left(s_1+s_2\sqrt{2}+s_3\sqrt{3}+s_4\sqrt{6}\right)\left(s_5-s_6\sqrt{2}\right)}{\left(s_5+s_6\sqrt{2}\right)\left(s_5-s_6\sqrt{2}\right)}\\
&=q_11+q_2\sqrt{2}+q_3\sqrt{3}+q_4\sqrt{6}
\end{align}

where $\;q_1,\;q_2,\;q_3,\;q_4\in\mathbb{Q}\;$.

Comment: You could make it significantly shorter by using that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)=\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2,\sqrt3]$, since the square roots are algebraic over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: You are right, but I have preferred to carry out the calculations without using the property that the square roots are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.